# Application.StartupPath called in a DLL in GAC, where it will resolved to?

Tags: c#, gac

I create an EXE ( let's call it `a.exe`), that calls a DLL (let's call it `b.dll`). Inside the `b.dll` there is this method

```
public string GetStartupPath()
{
  return Application.StartupPath;
}
```

I put the `a.exe` in `C:\Program Files\My Company\My App` folder. I install the `b.dll` in the GAC.

Now my question is, if I launch `C:\Program Files\My Company\My App\a.exe`, what will the method `GetStartupPath()` in `b.dll` returns?

I can do a simple sample to test, but I still decide to post this question here. Two reasons:

1. I suspect that on different machines, different answer will return.
2. For the benefit of other developers,  canonical response based on the official documentation available on StackOverflow is very useful.

Comment: It will give you path iof folder in which your application exe exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official docs:

> Gets the path for the executable file that started the application,
>   not including the executable name.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath(v=vs.110).aspx

So this means to me that it will give you the path where the exe lives.